# How do you reduce this lambda calculus expression?

Tags: lambda, computer-science, lambda-calculus

How do you reduce this lambda calculus expression?
I am trying to reduce NOT FALSE to TRUE with lambda calculus with the given definitions:

```
NOT = (λb.λx.λy.b y x)
FALSE = (λx.λy.y)
TRUE = (λx.λy.x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  NOT FALSE
= { expand definitions }
  (λb.λx.λy.b y x) (λx.λy.y)
= { beta-reduce, alpha-rename to avoid capture }
  λx.λy.(λa.λb.b) y x 
= { beta-reduce inside lambda, twice }
  λx.λy.x
= { definition of TRUE }
  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Given -

```
NOT = (λb.λx.λy.b y x)
FALSE = (λx.λy.y)
TRUE = (λx.λy.x)
```

Evaluate -

```
NOT FALSE
---
 \
(λb.λx.λy.b y x) FALSE      β [b := FALSE]
 --       -      -----
          _______/
         /
(λx.λy.FALSE y x)
```

Already we can see that `NOT` simply reverses the arguments to `FALSE`, which is effectively the same thing as `TRUE`. By reducing inside the lambda, we can prove they evaluate to the same result -

```
(λx.λy.FALSE y x) 
       -----
         \
(λx.λy.(λx.λy.y) y x)       β [x := y]
        --       -
         
(λx.λy.(λy.y) x)            β [y := x]
        __    _
         ____/
        /
(λx.λy.x)                   = TRUE
```